# How to make ansible email body break in lines and large font

Tags: ansible

Hi I have ansible playbook which sends email with attachment. but email body does not come in format all sentences comes in single line and very small font size.

Here is playbook -

```yaml
  - name: Sending an e-mail using the remote machine
    mail:
      host: localhost
      port: 25
      from:
      to:
      subject: Reports
      body: Hi,
            Hope you are doing well.
            Thanks,
            Megha
      attach:
        -  file.csv
        -  file.scv
```

This gives me output -

Hi,Hope you are doing well.Thanks,Megha

How can I have email body with line breaks and big font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use html using the parameter `subtype: html` and your `body` must have html

```yaml
  - name: Sending an e-mail using the remote machine
    mail:
      host: localhost
      port: 25
      from:
      to:
      subject: Reports
      subtype: html
      body:
        <h1>Hi,</h1>
        <p style="color:red">Hope you are doing well.</p>
        <strong>Thanks,</strong>
        <p style="color:green">Megha</p>
      attach:
        -  file.csv
        -  file.scv
```

Comment: This was pretty helpful guidance.  Two clarifications:

the subtype: html needs to be in the params like this:
mail:
  subtype: html

and in my testing, the body still needed quotes around the html or it threw errors.

thanks.  this was a huge help.